# Should my boiler be warm to the touch?

Tags: boiler

I was lightly dusting my boiler yesterday and it was quite warm to the touch.

The boiler is around ten years old and is tank fed.

Is it normal to feel warm?

Comment: It contains warm water. If it felt freezing cold then something is really wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. But it shouldn't be *hot*. You should be able to keep your hand on it (this is a general idea in electrical products). Newer boilers get less warm, but that's for reasons of energy efficiency (they're better insulated).

If its getting too hot to keep your hand on it, and it hasn't been serviced recently, it may be worth getting it generally checked over.

Comment: I'm not good with heat but I can easily keep my hands on it.